# How to check if a particular element exists in SuperObject?

Tags: json, delphi, superobject

I widely use the `SuperObject` JSON library. I need to be able to check if a particular element exists in an object or not. I can check the value of an element, for example an integer that doesn't exist returns `0`. However, `0` is one of the possible values if it does exist - so I can't depend on observing `0` for the element's existence. I checked the `ISuperObject` for methods that can do this (for example I'd expect something like `ISuperObject.Exists(const S: String): Boolean;`), but see nothing like this.

How can I check if a particular element exists in the JSON object or not?

Comment: Does this work: `if obj.AsObject.Exists('AreYouThere?') then`?

Comment: @LURD No, there's no such function, that was an example of what I was expecting.

Comment: `TSuperObject.AsObject` is of type `TSuperTableString`, which has an `Exists()` function.

Comment: @LURD Perhaps different version? Because I tried exactly that but there's nothing there. I currently use SuperObject version 1.2

Comment: It is in the trunk for version 1.2, [superobject](https://code.google.com/p/superobject/source/browse/superobject.pas) just get it there.

Comment: @LURD Hmm, 1.2.4 version history still ends at just 1.2, now I have to re-compile my library and all applications that use it :-| Post an answer with this and I'll accept that one.

Comment: @LURD I just did a search on the latest version's source and there's still no such function, are you sure your copy wasn't customized? The only thing I see with the word "exist" is `InheritedFieldExist`

Comment: Just follow my link above and download the zip file.

Comment: @LURD Okay I'm confused, I downloaded the latest ZIP file for 1.2.4 and didn't find this. The link you provided does have this. And a whole lot more units than the main download did.

Comment: This is often the case, so I have a habit of always checking out the latest update from the trunk. You can see that version 1.2.4 is from 2010, while the latest update was made this year.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The latest update of [SuperObject](https://github.com/hgourvest/superobject) contains an `Exists()` function.

```
var
  obj : ISuperObject;
begin
  obj := TSuperObject.ParseFile('..\..\SAMPLE.JSON',FALSE);
  if not obj.AsObject.Exists('FindMe') then begin
    WriteLn('Not found');
  end;
end;
```

If you should use the [dwsJSON](http://www.delphitools.info/2012/09/17/spotlight-on-dwsjson/) parser instead, there is a similar function to use:

```
if json['DoesNotExists'].ElementCount = 0 then begin
  WriteLn('Not found');
end;
```

Comment: It would be so nice if the "latest download" wasn't from 2010 - they need to update that.

Comment: @Jerry, they can't anymore. Google Code dropped download support (which might be the reason of quite huge migrations of several projects from there).

Answer (score 5):

You can check if certain field exists like this:

```
function FieldExists(const ASuperObject: ISuperObject; const AField: String): Boolean;
var
  o: ISuperObject;
begin
  o := ASuperObject.O[AField];
  result := Assigned(o);
end;
```

Basically, `json_superobject.O[field_name]` should return pointer to `ISuperObject` if `field_name` exists. Otherwise, it returns `nil`.